# am trying to encrypt a dictionary using cryptography

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, password-encryption

I'm trying to make a passowrd locker, that takes input and encrypt the data and also am trying to save the data into a dictionary and encrypt the values only.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet 
key = Fernet.generate_key() 
f = Fernet(key)
loc = {}  # an empty dict that stores the keys and values
title = input('enter your title: ')  # getting user title as key
secret = input('enter your secret: ') # getting secret as value to be encrypted
loc[title] = secret.encode()  #turning the value into a byte for encryption
print(f.encrypt(secret)) # but am having an error trying to get through
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: am trying to make a dictionary that stores key as tittle and values as secret and then encrypt the values( if possible encrypt all). but am having difficulty there.  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the difficulty? What is wrong with the code you have shown?

Comment: before print using the last statement, it throws an error ( expected 'bytes'.got 'str' instead.)  that the error am getting.

Answer (score 1):

Been a while but...

I would encrypt the entire dict but before you can do that you need to convert the dict to bytes:

```
import json
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet 
key = Fernet.generate_key() 
f = Fernet(key)
loc = {}
title = input('enter your title: ')
secret = input('enter your secret: ')
loc[title] = secret

encrypt_this = json.loads(loc).encode('utf-8')
encrypted = cryptography.fernet.Fernet(key).encrypt(encrypt_this)
```

and on the other end, you would decrypt it and convert the bytes back into a dict:

```
decrypt_this = cryptography.fernet.Fernet(key).decrypt(encrypted)
decrypted = json.loads(decrypt_this.decode('utf-8'))
```